# gitweb not showing details about repos

Tags: apache, msysgit

I have apache 2.4 on a windows 2008r2 serving a collection of bare msysgit repositories and I want to enable the gitweb frontend to browse the contents.  I am able to clone and push to repos.  When I configure gitweb the list of repos are shown but the contents of the repos are not visible.  For example the commit link shows "404 - Unknown commit object".

Here is the apache configuration for gitweb

```
Alias /gitweb/ "C:/Program Files (x86)/Git/share/gitweb/"
<Directory "C:/Program Files (x86)/Git/share/gitweb">
   <Files ~ "\.cgi$">
     Options +ExecCGI
   </Files>
   AllowOverride None
   Order allow,deny
   Allow from all
  DirectoryIndex gitweb.cgi
</Directory>
```

I modified the gitweb.cgi to point to the location of the msysgit's perl

```
#!C:/Program Files (x86)/Git/bin/perl
```

and the projectroot to

```
our $projectroot = "/C/git_repos";
```

Here is the apache configuration for git

```
SetEnv GIT_PROJECT_ROOT "C:/git_repos"
SetEnv GIT_HTTP_EXPORT_ALL
SetEnv REMOTE_USER=$REDIRECT_REMOTE_USER

ScriptAlias /git/ "C:/Program Files (x86)/Git/libexec/git-core/git-http-backend.exe/"
```

What am I missing?